# Merge two objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two JSON s, I want to add two JSON s in Javascript (Join JSOB object into JSON A),

JSON A :-

```
{

    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "subgroup": "2",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "3"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "subgroup": "2",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "subgroup": "2",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "4"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "3",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "4"
    }

}
```

JSON B :-

```
{

    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "3",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "4"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "4",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "3"
    }

}
```

Key names are similar in JSON A and JSON B . We can see, `subgroup 3` and `subgroup 4` are only present in `grp 4` and `grp 3` respectively (look into JSON B). I want to add each `subgroup` from JSON B into each `grp` in JSON A (except the `grp` s where those `subgroup` s are already present. Like in JSON A there is an entry with `subgroup 3` and `grp 4`, we will skip that.). Value of `Id`, `power` will be similar respectively. So, we want to add `subgroup 3` in the `grp 1, 2, 3` and add `subgroup 4` in the `group 1, 2, 4` . For `subgroup 3`, `power` and `id` value will be `2, 1` respectively and for `subgroup 4`, `power` and `id` value will be `1, 1` respectively.

Final JSON A output should be,

```
{

    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "subgroup": "2",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "3"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "subgroup": "2",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "subgroup": "2",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "subgroup": "1",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "4"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "3",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "4"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "3",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "3",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "3",
        "power": "2",
        "grp": "3"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "4",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "1"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "4",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "2"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "subgroup": "4",
        "power": "1",
        "grp": "4"
    }

}
```

I can add object into JSON,

```
var myObj = {
        "id" : id,
        "subgroup" : subgroup,
        "power" : power,
        "grp" : grp

}
```

What is the recommended way to join into JSON A from JSON B and skip the entries where `subgroup` is already present in the `grp`.

Comment: what you mean by 'add'? join two lists? count or multiply?

Comment: This seems more like merging than adding.

Answer (score 0):

JSON when parsed become object.

You can merge the objects like this

**ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) Standard Method**

```
/* For the case in question, you would do: */
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

/** There's no limit to the number of objects you can merge.
 *  All objects get merged into the first object. 
 *  Only the object in the first argument is mutated and returned.
 *  Later properties overwrite earlier properties with the same name. */
const allRules = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2, obj3, etc);
```

For more detailed description

visit - [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: you question is difficult to understand. write clearly and fix spelling mistakes.